# Xamarin.Auth Android Native UI not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.auth

I am using Xamarin.Auth to authenticate to my identity provider with implicit flow on Android. I can't get the native ui (chrome custom tabs) to work with Xamarin.Auth as I get the following error:

> UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 06-30 11:40:48.903 I/MonoDroid( 7670):
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method
>   'Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent.LaunchUrl' not found.
>   06-30 11:40:48.903 I/MonoDroid( 7670):   at
>   Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr
>   jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
>   native_savedInstanceState) [0x0000f] in
>   <93e2413825534efca8b597098003b511>:0  06-30 11:40:48.903 I/MonoDroid(
>   7670):   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:ce197f13-7701-4b2e-840f-19029a77ef6c
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr) 06-30 11:40:48.913 W/art     ( 7670): JNI
>   RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for
>   android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable 06-30 11:40:48.918 D/HockeyApp(
>   7670): Writing unhandled exception to:
>   /data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp/files/9a7dae18-3c5a-4e97-b7cb-4a3f1581c690.stacktrace

My authenticator is set up like this:

```
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
    AuthSettings.ClientId, 
    AuthSettings.Scope,
    new Uri(AuthSettings.AuthorizeUrl), 
    new Uri(AuthSettings.RedirectUrl),
    null,
    true);
```

I am not using linking either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google search I came accross an issue thread on a github page for the 'SharePlugin' for Xamarin, fortunately James Montemagno is in their helping out. The issue listed is similar to yours so for reference purposes it can be found [Here](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin/issues/40).

It appears to have been a fairly common issue with this method 'Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent::LaunchUrl'. In that thread they obviously mention that:

> Release Mode => Linker option => None , Every thing works.

So that's worth double checking, to make sure that's what you're doing. (I realise you've mentioned you've had a look at the linked assemblies, but always worth a double check).

There is also some conversation on the GitHub repository for Xamarin.Auth iteself, a particular issue found [Here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/167) talks about the versions of both Xamarin Auth and Xamarin Forms, needing to match in a certain way, I would suggest updating xamarin.forms to it's latest version, and trying again, perhaps even downgrading Xamarin.Auth.

> It worked with 1.5.0-alpha-03. Tried with 1.5.0-alpha-09 but it
>   failed.

Comment: I have tried the linker option, and have tried different versions. Still no dice. It seems the issue is active on github, so I will probably follow that.